# libcurl not returning right binary

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, libcurl

I have this code, it downloads a file from the internet through ssl and it seems to work fine. but when i try to run the executable output it says it is not compatible with 64 bit version of windows. Am I configuring size_t wrong ? What is the wrong with the program.. Thank you

```
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
    #include <openssl/ssl.h>
    #include <curl/curl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    FILE * myFile = fopen("min.exe", "a+");

    size_t writefunction(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
    {
      printf("called.. writeFunction\r\n");
      fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, myFile);
      return (nmemb*size);
    }

        int main(void)
        {
          CURL *ch;
          CURLcode rv;
          char caPath[128];
          char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

          rv = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
          ch = curl_easy_init();


          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://someapp.herokuapp.com/");

         /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
           /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);

          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, *writefunction);
          //rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

          printf("set Up CA Path..\r\n");
          memset(caPath,'0',sizeof(caPath));
         // strcpy(caPath,"/home/test/SSL_Server");
          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH,caPath);

          rv = curl_easy_perform(ch);
          printf("curl easy perform done..\r\n");

          if(rv == CURLE_OK)
            printf("*** transfer succeeded ***\n");
          else
          {
             printf("*** transfer failed..****\n");
             perror("failed:");
          }
    }
```

Comment: If you download the program using `curl`'s commandline interface, can you execute it then?

Comment: yes it downloads @TedLyngmo and i exeecute

Comment: Does it get the same size as when you download it using the program above?

Comment: actually no, there is 1kb difference @TedLyngmo

Comment: You are opening the output file in text mode, use binary mode instead. Also, you are opening the file in append mode, why not in create/overwrite mode? Also, this question is tagged [c++], but there is nothing C++ about this code, everything in it is for C instead. Also, since you are using `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, consider using [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) to pass your `FILE*` into the callback instead of using a global variable. Or, since you are using `FILE*`, you can use just `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` by itself and omit `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`.

Comment: `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` crashes with this, probably the way i handle `writeFunction` yes the problem is that i forgot to add binaries  there @RemyLebeau

Comment: "*`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` crashes with this*" - then you are likely using it wrong. "*probably the way i handle `writeFunction`*" - the `writeFunction()` you showed is fine, I just don't recommend using a global variable with it.